# 2013 - RBS configured but not saving files

Tags: 2013, rbs

I'm using SharePoint 2013 with SQL Server 2012 SP1.

I have implemented RBS following this [TechNet guide](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/bogdang/2014/12/04/install-and-configure-rbs-with-sharepoint-2013-and-sql-server-2012/):

And also checking [here](https://rogierdijkman.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/configure-remote-blob-storage-in-sharepoint/).

Everything was done as described without errors, also from SharePoint PowerShell I can see that my WebApplication has RBS enabled, with 'FilestreamProvider_1' set as ActiveProviderName and '1048576' as MinimumBlogStorageSize value. Some tables were created in my content database, also the folder 'J:\BLOBStore' exists in my local disk (the destination of the BLOB files)

**Then I tried and I have uploaded a file of 15MB to a document library in my SharePoint site, but I can't see the file saved in my storage** (obviously I'm not expecting the same uploaded file, but one with no extension and different filename).

Trying to open the uploaded file from SharePoint it works, so actually it is correctly saved. But, I don't know where.

*Any suggestion?
Is there something else I can check?*

Comment: did you solve this issue? I'm facing the same. If I set min value to (10*1024) - small files are stored to blob too. If i set value to (100*1024) - even 10MB file is not stored to BLOB Storage.
In an experimental way I figured out that minimal valid value for this settings is 64 Kb. If value is less, it works fine. If value is greater, no files are stored to BLOB irrespectively to their size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the problem:

```
$cdb.RemoteBlobStorageSettings.MinimumBlobStorageSize=1048576
```

1048576 is not 1MB as described in the guides. I've set this value to 0 and now BLOB are saved correctly.

```
$cdb.RemoteBlobStorageSettings.MinimumBlobStorageSize=0
```

I've read is not suggested to use RBS with file with size under 500KB, so I'll probably change this value again.